# Excel formula for counting the number of incidents of a word in a column?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Is there a quicker way of searching for terms without typing each one into the formula? Like, say I have a column that has a bunch of names of locations and I want to find out how many times each one comes up.

This is the formula for when I type in the locations:

```
=COUNTIF($F$2:$F$274,"*AD library*")
```

I just modify the AD library to the next one, say monastery so it would be

```
=COUNTIF($F$2:$F$274,"*monastery*")
```

Is there another way of getting the same info without having to type in each one (it's a big sheet with a lot of locations).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the insert tab and insert a pivot table.

Then drag the header (locations?) you want the count of to `row labels` and any other header to the `value` field (preferably something with text).

Now the pivot should give you the count of each item.
If you don't have a column with text then choose any other and you need to switch from sum to count in the `value` field settings.

Answer (score 1):

use PivotTable on just that one column.  Put that column in both rows and Values:

[image]